# Prometheus Targets : server returned HTTP status 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio, istio-prometheus

In my K8s Cluster, I have a prometheus stack installed via helm.

`prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --version 34.9.0`

In the prometheus "targets", some targets giving below error while some others are working.

> > server returned HTTP status 502 Bad Gateway

See the image below for reference,

[image: server returned HTTP status 502 Bad Gateway]

If we try the matrics endpoint directly, it gives metric response fine (tried in browser) on the same ports ( More over these are not manual configuration, its auto configured by the prometheus stack helm chart itself.)

I compared ServiceMonitor configurations, containers configuration of the one working and not working - all seems same.

Notes

- I have "Istio" Service mesh enabled ( istio-injection=enabled ).
- All the prometheus related resources are in same namespace "monitoring"
- Some resources in the same namespace is giving proper response. (ex: prometheus-stack-kube-prom-kubelet, prometheus-stack-kube-prom-prometheus) , while others giving 502 error.

How to fix it, and what causing the error.